# How to submit a GET request with json input using apache bench?

Tags: http, apachebench

The request for our service looks something like this:

```
GET http://[SERVICE]/Node:[id].Build?format=mime1,mime2,...,mimeN&template-id=[templateid]
Accept: multipart/mixed
Content-Type: application/json
body: json document
```

I am attempting to use ApacheBench to test benchmark this. Here is the call I am using:

```
ab -n 10 -c 2 -T 'application/json' -H 'Accept: multipart/mixed' 'http://phx5qa01c-02b0.stratus.phx.qa.ebay.com/.Build?format=text/html,text/plain&template-id=29b1468f-c8c3-db23-2f6f-74e112795540'
```

This call goes through, and results in an error since the expected json data is not there.Is there a way in ab to supply the necessary json along with this request. I see there are -p and -u commands to specify an input file, but those are for puts and posts.

Comment: I question why you're using the `GET` method to send data in the first place. Though doing so [is not technically prohibited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15210810/895378) it's unlikely that your use case doesn't violate RFC 2616's requirements for safety and idempotence. Are you using the JSON document as a query string replacement to make a complex query from the resource? Please share your motivation for doing this.

Comment: The reason why we're doing this is because we require a lot of variables to be passed in, in order to specify exactly what to get. We considered putting these as query parameters, but using json made more sense. We don't send data per se, just send the criteria/variables that describe what we need back. Is there a way to do this using ab?

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense, though I would still suggest simplifying the API to provide specific, addressable parameters via the URI query string. For example, instead of providing a massive query engine from one monolithic resource, break it up into sub-resources for querying certain types of resources. I'm fairly certain there's no way to do this with `ab`, and there's a fairly good reason: HTTP works well because it's standardized. Creating your own query scheme via a GET body complicates things unnecessarily and should generally be discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize that this answer is six years late, but I think it is worth posting since I was banging my head against a wall on a very similar issue to this, in which I was trying to load test a URL which returned only JSON data, and my solution might help other readers encountering this issue.  My issue was I kept specifying the -H option when I didn't need to.  That kept making the server to send back an HTTP 406 response code (Not Acceptable) to my AB request.  During most of my my troubleshooting, I had also kept `-T 'application/json'` in the AB request as well when I didn't need it.  That is only used in conjunction with PUTs or POSTs (when using the -p switch).  So I removed -H, and -T, and it worked.  All that said, I see those two issues here. We need to be mindful that AB uses the GET method by default.

1. You are constraining AB by appending extra custom headers to the
   request, by using the -H option: `-H 'Accept: multipart/mixed'`, which
   might make your target server think it's an invalid request and stop the
   sequence right then and there.  Just don't use -H unless you have a
   really good reason why.
2. You are using the -T option: `-T 'application/json'` which
   only works when you specify that in conjunction with -p and you
   don't have -p anywhere in your command, which you don't want to use anyway since you are sending a GET and not a PUT or a POST.

So to fix this, simply remove both the -T and -H options, and it should work.  *Reminder to other readers:  If on Windows, enclose the URL in double-quotes whenever it contains special characters like a "&", or a "?", as in this case.*

```
ab -n 10 -c 2 'http://phx5qa01c-02b0.stratus.phx.qa.ebay.com/.Build?format=text/html,text/plain&template-id=29b1468f-c8c3-db23-2f6f-74e112795540'
```