# Problems with $_FILES in PHP

Tags: php, file, upload

I am trying to make a site where I can upload pictures.

```
<form action="edit.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

In the `edit.php`-file I have chosen to use the example from W3Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). When I get to the editor-page it won't upload because the file is a invalid type (filetype not found in the array).

After many different tries I putted this code at the top of the file:

```
if (!isset($_FILES['file'])) { die("Not found!"); }
```

When I loaded the editor page again I got the error-message I had put there myself. It seems like the file I am sending from the `index.php`-page won't be founded in `edit.php`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Opinion: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: Your form's method should be `method='post'` not `method='get'`

Comment: To familiarize yourself with the structure of `$_FILES` once you have gotten it to populate properly, do `print_r($_FILES);` in the receiving code `edit.php`.

Comment: Thank you Michael Berkowski. It worked after I changed the form-method!

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this and then in your edit.php file you can try to print the $_FILES array.

```
//edit.php
print '<pre>';
print_r($_FILEs);


// index.php
<html>
<body>

<form action="edit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['size'])):

$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
//play with the file then
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<form action="edit.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

See here for discussion on this topic.
[File uploading using GET Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201976/file-uploading-using-get-method)

Answer (score 0):

Use post method. 
index.php code :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="edit.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

edit.php (Just printed Files array and output is as follows)
Code: 
    ";
    print_r($_FILES);
    print ""; 
    ?>

Output : 
    Array
    (
    [uploadedfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => ipmsgclip_r_1398851755_0.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpktZwLl
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 155
        )
    )

If file uploading has any error then it will come in this array as [error]. 
For instance : I your uploaded file's size is exceeds the mentioned file size (1000000)
Then output Array will be : 
   Array
  (
    [uploadedfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => d.png
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 2
            [size] => 0
        )
   )