# Laravel, upload image errors

Tags: image, laravel

I know, that there are many many cases about this theme already, but I looked them through, and could not find desired. Also I noticed that not a lot of the users got their answer.
I am working with Laravel5, and I'm trying to upload a picture. Simple upload, just save any picture in public/img folder.
I have looked up some tutorials and came up with this code:
View form:

```
<form action="{{URL::to('adminPanel/addImg/done/'.$projectId)}}" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="image" type="file" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Ielādēt"/>
</form>
```

And the controller code:

```
public function addImageDone($id) {
         $file            = Input::file('image');
         $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/';
         $filename        = $id;
         $file->move($destinationPath);   
    }
```

I keep getting this error :

> Call to a member function move() on a non-object

And I am sure, that the chosen file is image.

I would appreciate any help

**So its done,** the main issue was the POST part! Also the file format, but here are the correct code, that adds the image:
form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{!! URL::to('adminPanel/addImg/done/'.$projectId) !!}" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> //this part is to make POST method work
        <input name="image" type="file" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Ielādēt"/>
    </form>
```

controller:

```
public function addImageDone($id) {
         $file = Input::file('image');
         $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/';
         $file->move($destinationPath, $id.'.png');            
    }
```

Comment: You have method="get"  instead of method="POST"  also try doing a `dd(Input::file('image'))` and check if your form is really submitting your image

Comment: is POST method obligatory in uploading images? Because I thought i could use get instead, because I am making new view after the upload with the same controller function...

Comment: also I'm not really sure why, but it gives me an token mismatch error each time I try to sue POST method

Comment: because you have the middleware responsible CSRF protection active, you should read Laravel Documentation http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: Also this why you can't submit files using GET method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201976/file-uploading-using-get-method

Comment: Thanks, turns out I had to just add one silly row 
"<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">"
to my form, and POST methods started working, but u already knew it.
Now, if i run my code with post method, I'm creating weird fille in the destination folder instead of the image. The file, that shoves up is: phpXXXX.tmp
Also the thing is that I have to pass the id from the view to controller to be able name the image file by it.

Comment: Once again try reading the Files documentation it's pretty simple http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#files if after that you can't make it work I suggest that you put a little effort on this question by editing and posting your controller code and other useful info

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are using Laravel 4.2 or 5.0. But..

I recommend you to use illuminate/html - Form class. Try to use POST instead GET to upload files (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15210810/781251, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1 , http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php , http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

### If Laravel 4.2:

View:

```
{{ Form::open(['url'=>'adminPanel/addImg/done' . $projectId , 'files' => true , 'method' => 'POST']) }}

    <label for="file">File</label>   
    {{ Form::file('file') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller:

```
public function postImage()
{
    if( ( $file = Input::file('file') ) != null && $file->isValid() )
    {
        $file->move('destination','my_file_new_name.extension');

        return Redirect::back();
    }

    throw new \Exception('Error while upload file');
}
```

### Laravel 5.0

View:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'adminPanel/addImg/done' . $projectId , 'files' => true , 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

    <label for="file">File</label>   
    {!! Form::file('file') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    if( ( $file = $request->file('file') ) != null && $file->isValid() )
    {
        $file->move('destination','my_file_new_name.extension');

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    throw new \Exception('Error while upload file');
}
```

To create a file with a new name and keep the extension:

```
$ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$newName = str_random(20) . '.' . $ext;

$file->move( storage_path('images') , $newName );
```

Now, you have a new name with the same extension. To validate if your file is an image or..whatever, use Validator.

Comment: I have a question about extension of the file part.
I got the upload, but it uploads the file as a unrecognized file. And I'm sure that its the image, because if I open it as a, for example, bmp file, it open the image. how can i set the file format of the image?

Comment: You can create a new name and grab the "client extension". I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, the problem wasn't with the image name, it was with the format. But thanks, because of your answer, I got the correct result. Just that I was unfamiliar with he syntax a bit..      $file->move($destinationPath, $id.'.png');     
there has to be a dot before png ans also another one right after $id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form method="POST" action="{!! URL::to('adminPanel/addImg/done/'.$projectId) !!}" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="image" type="file" />
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Ielādēt"/>
</form>
```

And get the image as

```
public function postImage(Request $request) {
    $image = $request->file("image");
```