# PHP File Upload Without Form

Tags: php, upload, file-transfer

Is there a way that I can allow a user to upload a file by providing the filename/directory for the file in a get variable (or some way other than using a form)?

Essentially, I'd like the user to be able to do something like this:

```
http://example.com/upload.php?file=C:/files/myFile.txt
```

and have upload.php handle the upload.

I've been looking at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) to try to figure out how to do this, along with a couple of other resources, but they're all focused around using forms.

I need to be able to allow an app to go to my php page and provide a file to be uploaded without a prompt.

It doesn't have to be in a GET, but I CANNOT PROMPT for a file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201976/file-uploading-using-get-method
I send you back to this topic!

Comment: You don't you use the POST method?

Comment: How can use the POST method to specify a file on the user's system to upload without using a form or prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that's not possible. You can upload file using post request. Why are you trying to send data using get request?

Comment: I'm developing a page that will interact with an app running on an ipad. The app should be able to automatically connect and upload a file. There should be no file upload prompt.