# Uploaded file is not passing through JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here i'm trying to pass uploaded file and a text input from HTML->JavaScript->PHP. But it is only passing the text input and failed to pass the file , i'm not getting that file in PHP. As a result it is showing undefined index error for "$u_file" in the PHP file. I don't understand where is the problem.

Here goes the HTML file

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="">
            <h2><b>Post your job</b></h2><br><br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Job Position:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jName" placeholder="Enter job name" name="jName" required>
                    <p id="jErr"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Add some detailed description:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="u_file" value="u_file" type="file" name="u_file" size="5000000" multiple onchange="showname()"><br><br>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>


            <div class="container-fluid text-center">
            <br><button name="submitJob" id="submitJob" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="job_checker()">Submit</button>
            <p id="submitJobErr"></p></div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here goes the JavaScript file

```
signFlagj = 0;

function job_checker() {
   checkJobName();
    databasejobEntry();
}

function checkJobName() {

    var jobnameET = document.getElementById("jName");
    var jobnameError = document.getElementById("jErr");

    jobname = jobnameET.value;
    console.log(jobname);

    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(jobname)){
        jobnameError.innerHTML = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        signFlagj = 1;
    }
    else {
        jobnameError.innerHTML = "";
    }

}

function showname() {
    jobFilename = document.getElementById('u_file');
    console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).name);
    console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).size);
    console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).type);
}

function databasejobEntry() {

    if(signFlagj==1) {
        console.log("fill up correctly!");
        alert("Sign up correctly!");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Selected file: ' + jobFilename.files.item(0).name);
        console.log(jobname);

        var submitError = document.getElementById("submitJobErr");
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log(this.readyState);
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                console.log(this.status);
                var response = xhttp.responseText;
                console.log(response);
                submitError.innerHTML=response;
                alert(response);
                if(String(response.trim()) === "Success") {
                    alert("Successfully submitted :)");
                    window.location.href = "uploadJob.html";
                }
            }
        }

        xhttp.open("GET", "uploadJob.php?jobname="+jobname+"&jobFilename="+jobFilename,true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

}
```

Here goes the PHP file

```
require_once('DBconnection.php');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);

$val="";
$jobName = $_GET["jobname"];
echo "$jobName";

$u_file = $_FILES['jobFilename'];

$file_type = $_FILES['jobFilename']['type'];
$file_size = $_FILES['jobFilename']['size'];
$file_name = $_FILES['jobFilename']['name'];

print_r($u_file);
//echo "****************";

$currentdir = getcwd();
$targetfolder = $currentdir . "/testupload/";
// echo "****************";
print_r($targetfolder);

$targetfile = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['jobFilename']['name']) ;

//print_r($targetfolder);


print_r($currentdir);
//echo "****************";

$uploadOk=1;

print_r($file_type);

if ($file_type != "application/pdf" && $file_type != "image/png" && $file_type != "image/jpeg" && $file_type != "image/jpg") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & PDF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}


if (file_exists($targetfile)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}


if($uploadOk==0){
    echo "Problem in uploading file";
}

else {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['jobFilename']['tmp_name'], $targetfile)) {

        $fileUpQueryjob = "INSERT INTO jobs (job_name,job_filename) VALUES ('$jobName','$file_name')";
        $upJob = $db->query($fileUpQueryjob);
        if ($upJob == true) {
            $val = "Success";
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['jobFilename']['name']). " is uploaded";
        }
        else
            echo "Error: " . $fileUpQueryjob . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
    }
}

//echo "$val";
$db->close();
```

Comment: You should use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API if you want to [fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) via AJAX.

Comment: How do i get the file in php then?

Comment: PHP takes data URLs, so you can just use [file_put_contents();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use POST request instead of GET request. If necessary warp it in new FormData and post it.

Comment: A file cannot be transferred by GET request. Read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201976/file-uploading-using-get-method

Comment: You can warp file in FormData like, var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("thefile", file);
xhr.send(formData);

Comment: sorry i don't understand