# How can I get a file uploaded from a view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, logistic-regression

I am trying to capture a CSV file in my `Request` within my controller. I have been reading the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem) on using the file system in Laravel but it seems to return `NULL`.

Inside of my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('dataframe'); # This returns null every time
        if(isset($file)):

            $dataset = new CsvDataset($file, 1);
            $vectorizer = new TokenCountVectorizer(new WordTokenizer());
            $tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();

            $samples = [];
            foreach ($dataset->getSamples() as $sample)
                $samples[] = $sample[0];

            $vectorizer->fit($samples);
            $vectorizer->transform($samples);

            $tfIdfTransformer->fit($samples);
            $tfIdfTransformer->transform($samples);

            $dataset = new ArrayDataset($samples, $dataset->getTargets());
            $randomSplit = new StratifiedRandomSplit($dataset, 0.1);

            $classifier = new SVC(Kernel::RBF, 10000);
            $classifier->train($randomSplit->getTrainSamples(), $randomSplit->getTrainLabels());

            $predictedLabels = $classifier->predict($randomSplit->getTestSamples());

            $viewVar = (object) [
                'labels' => $predictedLabels,
                'score'  => Accuracy::score($randomSplit->getTestLabels(), $predictedLabels)
            ];

            return view('home')->with('prediction', $viewVar);

        endif;

        return view('home');
    }
```

Inside of my view:

```
<p>You can upload your dataframe below.</p>
    <form method='GET'>
        <input type='file' name='dataframe'>
        <button type='submit' name='upload'>Predict</button>
    </form>
@if (isset($prediction))
    <p> Score: {{ $prediction->score }} </p>
@endif
```

When I `var_dump()` the request, I can see the `languages.csv` file I upload. How can I access this file within the `$request` variable?

Comment: Your form is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to submit a document, you must use POST and enctype :

```
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='dataframe'>
    <button type='submit' name='upload'>Predict</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So, I cannot submit this using GET? I'll have to use POST?

Comment: Since GET appends the form data to the current URL, no. It will only contain the name of the file, not the file content. GET data is limited around 2048 chars, so you guess you can't put a file in this.

Comment: @Jaquarh i think this could be very much helpful regarding your doubts : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201976/file-uploading-using-get-method

Comment: After updating it to POST, including the `enctype`, this is working. Thank you for this answer, I'll accept when I can.